# Migration period between WebForms to ASP.NET MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I understand that ASP.NET WebForms and ASP.NET MVC are completely different approaches. Since I am not yet ready to move to ASP.NET MVC (insufficient knowledge), I am interested would the following adjustments make it easier for a later upgrade/transfer of a site from WebForms to MVC (from a front-end viewpoint)?

- Disable Viewstate
- Avoid using AjaxControlToolkit
- Avoid using ASP.NET controls
- Use html controls + jquery instead
- Avoid using Web Forms
- Avoid using PostBack
- Avoid using user controls
- Avoid using update panels

Basically I want to continue develop project in webforms, but would like to add all future changes in a way so it would be easier to move from webforms to mvc. Would like to get suggestion would the following changes help me do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you have business in a separate layer, it would be a little bit easier because if you implement all the businesses in webform code behind, you should re-implement all the business in controllers when you upgrade to MVC. but if you implement business in another layer, you will separate your concerns.
I've written a blog post about hints on using web form [here](http://ehsanghanbari.com/Post/125/aspnet-dont-do-that-do-this). as you want to migrate to mvc in the future, if you use basic html tags and controls, it would be easier on working with MVC View (razor or aspx). rather than all the above, you can also use MVP patter in webform and remove the code behind in your web form app (the main idea behind MVC).
Hope it helps...

Comment: it is not really an answer, but you provided some interesting facts.

Comment: thanks, you can ask your questions and needs in detail. for example about routing, membership, bundle, ... in that case I can help you better.

Answer (score 1):

It would not simplify migration process. Because you would have to re-implement all front end from the beginning. You could only use your business logic if you have such abstraction.

Comment: I am not sure I agree with you on this. I think re-implementation would occur only for heavily use of forms and masterpages/layouts. In case of better use of javascript and jquery why would there be a need for re-implementation?

Comment: @John you are right. If you use html controls and javascript instead of using webforms features you would have to implement only mvc controllers, but all the front end would stay the same

Comment: thanks for confirming my thinking. I will continue develop webforms for this project until i have enough knowledge to start using mvc.

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understand how you can avoid using Web Forms and PostBacks in ASP.NET *WebForms*. Anyway, if you use only HTML and Javascript for your front end *logic* and AJAX for data,  the future migration should be pretty straightforward.
You could consider mixing WebForms and MVC in one solution sometime if you work with ASP.NET Web Stack 5.

Comment: client side scripting would avoid use of some webforms functionality, but could not avoid the concept